# Filter condition for uploaDir using ssh2-sftp-client (NodeJS) for only certain files

Tags: node.js, regex, express, sftp, glob

In my nodejs code I am using ssh2-sftp-client (https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client) to transfer some files to a remote server :

The files in my directory are like :

```
srcDir :

file1.py
file2.py
test.csv
```

My sample code is like below:

```
   let SftpClient = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
   let sftp = new SftpClient();
   sftp.connect(connSettings)
         .then(() => {
          return sftp.uploadDir(srcDir,dst);   //need filter here
          }).then(rslt => {
                           ..
    }
```

The code uploads all the files in srcDir (py and csv) to destination but I want only the python files copied to destination. I can see filter parameter but I am unable to figure out the expression to achieve it.

I am  not sure about the pattern from the example I have tried with

```
/*.py/ 
/^(.*\.(?!(py)$))?[^.]*$/i 
/^[^.py]/
```

etc but did not seem to help.

Thanks
[1]: https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client

Comment: Worked with version 6.0.0 of ssh2-sftp-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with version 6.0.0 of ssh2-sftp-client